# How to make Git temporarily ignore ~/.gitconfig?

Tags: git

How can I make a Git command temporarily ignore my `~/.gitconfig`?

I can set `GIT_CONFIG=/dev/null` to make `git config` ignore `~/.gitconfig`, but this doesn't affect other Git commands.

I can hide my `~/.gitconfig`, e.g. `mv ~/.gitconfig{,.hidden}`, but this is annoying since I have to move it back later and it affects Git globally.

## Use Cases

- Scripting Git: restrict to default settings for portability.
- Debugging Git: restrict to default settings for reproducibility.

Comment: Why do you want to do it?  What is your use case?

Comment: @Sigi: right now I'm debugging Git, and in the past I've wanted this when scripting Git.

Comment: Amazingly, there does not seem to be an option to `git` which would make it ignore the config(s).  Maybe you should submit a request to the Git maintainers to include that possibility.

Comment: asked here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/1ehWsItL8vE not sure whether it's the right place; btw the feature should be: override the location, not ignore it; override is more powerful and includes ignoring (by specifying an empty file for eg). Suggested command: `git --gitconfigfile=~/.gitconfig_temp diff`

Comment: I've now also asked here: https://public-inbox.org/git/CANri+Ey71QbWxNH+RhMfYuUSDEpYtv28ushUhK8Tt0xWUAU9iw@mail.gmail.com/T/#u

Answer (score 11):

I found a decent workaround: Git can't use my `~/.gitconfig` if it can't find it:

```
HOME= git <args>
```

works! Here `HOME=` effectively unsets `HOME` for the duration of the command `git <args>`.

More careful but longer versions include

```
HOME=/dev/null git <args>
```

and

```
(unset HOME; git <args>)
```

Comment: More precisely, it sets `HOME` to the empty string.

Comment: This might break versions of git before 1.8.4; see `Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt` in the git source tree. And git config files (such as `<repo>/.git/config`) can refer to `$HOME` or `~`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I guess you are referring to "When `$HOME` is misconfigured to point at an unreadable directory, we
   used to complain and die. Loosen the check." in the release notes. Thanks!