# Git config: changing some setting from global to local

Tags: git, git-config

I am currently working on a repo that needs LFS to access large files.
So in my Git config I have

```
$git config --list

....
lfs.url=https://me@<lfs domain>
```

However I am starting to work on another repo and it seems that this setting affects my ability to clone this repo. I am having multiple problems, one of them is me not being able to checkout to any branches after I clone that repo. Apparently this repo uses a different LFS settings but that is just a guess so I can not set this locally.

It has come to my attention that the global setting above is the one impeding me work on the second repo. But I cannot eliminate it because it will impede my work on the first repo in which I have tight deadlines.

What can I do in this scenario?

One idea I thought would be to do that lfs.url setting somehow locally instead of global.

### Edit

I just realized that my first "repo" is actually a collection of repos managed by "repo", so it would be better to ask:

Is there a way so that I can clone the second repo *without* the global settings above for that repo? (ignore that locally)

Comment: If it is really just the one setting I would deactivate that setting in your global config, clone the repo, add a local setting and then activate the global one again. I assume you won't work on your other projects while you are cloning another. Maybe look at [How to make git temporarily ignore gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400449/how-to-make-git-temporarily-ignore-gitconfig)